# Find the probability that X = Y

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus

I have a joint continuous distribution defined by the p.d.f. $f(x, y)$. I know how to go about finding things like $\mathbb{P}(X > Y)$, $\mathbb{P}(X + Y > 2)$ et cetera. However I have no idea how to find $\mathbb{P}(X = Y)$. What integrals should I calculate, and with what limits? Should I just make the substitution $x = y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probability is generally $0$, for the same reason that $\mathbb{P}(X = x)$ is $0$ for any particular $x$.

To find a probability involving $X$ and $Y$, you integrate their joint density function over the corresponding region of the $xy$-plane. If your joint density function is actually supported on a 2-dimensional region of the plane, then integrating over any 1-dimensional subset of the plane will give you $0$, because it can be fit inside a region with arbitrarily small measure. (Here, "measure" refers to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$.)